# My binded property doesn't change based on Datepicker date xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ok so heres the basic of my app : On opening im in the AcceuilPage.xaml, i click the + icon to add a new item to the collection in AcceuilPage.

Then it brings me to the NewFormPage.xaml which i use to fill a data form in which i have a Datepicker binded to Date.

In AcceuilPage.xaml i have two things binded to Date to get the month and the day, BUT they stay to default date whenever i save something to the agenda ( they don't update to the datepicker date)

I tried to change agenda.Date in my saveButtonClicked method in NewFormPage.xaml.cs to : agenda.Date = Date; but it didn't let me "implicitly convert DatePicker to DateTime. ( it worked when i changed it to Datetime.Now but i want the selected date from the datepicker)

Thanks for your help.

**Part of the code in AcceuilPage.xaml in my Views folder**

```
                            <Expander Grid.Column="1">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd}'}" TextColor="#008A00" FontSize="27" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                                            <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MMMM}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                            <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="GoToFormPage"></ImageButton>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F2F4F8" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="#008A00" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Duration}" TextColor="#2F3246" FontSize="12" Margin="0,-10,0,0"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Expander.Header>
```

**Agenda.cs in my models folder**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using Calculette.Database;

namespace Calculette.Models
{
    public class Agenda
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        //public ObservableCollection<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }
        //public string Color { get; set; }
       // public string Name { get; set; }

       // public string Time { get; set;  }
    }
}
```

**NewFormPage.xaml in views folder ( this is the form i feel with the datepicker)**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    
    
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Date de calcul:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            <DatePicker x:Name="Date" Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}" FontFamily="ROBOTO" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></DatePicker>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout >
            <Label Text="Description" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="Description" Text="{Binding Topic}"/>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Durée quotidienne" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="Duree" Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Text="{Binding Duration}"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Niveau de pression dB(A)" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="Pression" Text="{Binding Pression}"/>
        </StackLayout>


        <Editor Text="{Binding Commentary}"
            x:Name="Commentary" 
            AutoSize="TextChanges" 
            Placeholder="Commentaires" />

        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Save" x:Name="SaveButton"  TextColor="#008A00" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#1A961A" Clicked="SaveButtonClicked"></Button>
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

**NewFormPage.xaml.cs in views folder**

```
using Calculette.Models;
using Calculette.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Calculette.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewFormPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewFormPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = new Agenda();
            
        }

        async void SaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var agenda = (Agenda)BindingContext;
           //agenda.Date = DateTime.Now;
            await App.Database.SaveAgendaAsync(agenda);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either bind your Picker properly

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Date" Date="{Biding Date}" ... />
```

and set the default value in your VM

```
public Agenda() 
{
  ...
  Date = DateTime.Now;
  ...
}
```

OR, if you want to manually assign it

> agenda.Date = Date; but it didn't let me "implicitly convert
> DatePicker to DateTime.

this is because `Date` is a UI control, not a `DateTime`.  To get the selected value from the `DatePicker`, use the `Date` property

```
agenda.Date = Date.Date;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with agenda.Date = Date.Date; Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`<DatePicker x:Name="Date" Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}"` - this is **not** binding. This is setting the date to be a specific static date (today). You have to change it to `Date="{Binding Date}"`. This way the `DatePicker` will be bound to the `Agenda`'s `Date` property.

Comment: You're right, i thought it would work with x:Name="Date" because in the first place i had only  Date="{Binding Date}" BUT my problem is that my Datepicker is initializing to a Default Date value from years 1900.. so i added Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today} which would set my picker to todays Date, so is there a way to write this line but adding a Binding to it also. Cause right now it seems like i can't give two property to my Date element

Comment: see my answer - you need to bind to your Model, AND you need to initialize your model to use the correct default value